# Why does my fetch request have issue with concating strings for the URL

Tags: javascript, fetch, concatenation

I am trying to access the https://api.open5e.com to make a search tool
I am able to do a fetch request for instance to get https://api.open5e.com/monsters/?type=dragon

And that will return the information I need
But I am trying to do it programmatically so I can apply different filters with ease

However no matter what combination of string I do I get a "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

```
const APILINKS = [
    'https://api.open5e.com/monsters/?',
    'https://api.open5e.com/spells/?',
    'https://api.open5e.com/weapons/?'
];

async function populateList(url, query) {

    document.getElementById("queryResults").innerHTML = "<p>Loading data</p>";

    console.log(APILINKS[url] + query);
    let link = "https://api.open5e.com/monsters/?" + query
    //let response = await fetch(link);
    //let response = await fetch(APILINKS[url] + query);
    //let response = await fetch('https://api.open5e.com/monsters/?' + query);
    //let response = await fetch('https://api.open5e.com/monsters/?type=dragon');
    
    if (response.ok) { // if HTTP-status is 200-299
        let json = await response.json();
        let count = json['count'];
        console.log(count);
        response = await fetch(link + "&limit=" + count);
        //response = await fetch(APILINKS[url] + query + "&limit=" + count);
        //response = await fetch('https://api.open5e.com/monsters/?' + query + "&limit=" + count);
        //response = await fetch("https://api.open5e.com/monsters/?type=dragon" + "&limit=" + count);
        
        if (response.ok) { // if HTTP-status is 200-299
            json = await response.json();
            
            populateTable(json, ELEMENTLABELS[url]);
        } else {
            alert("HTTP-Error: " + response.status);
        }
    } else {
        alert("HTTP-Error: " + response.status);
    }
}
```

In the comments I have included the different ways I have tried to add the concat string to the method
The only way that works is hardcoding the string in

Can anyone see why this just will not work for me?

EDIT: I have included how its called from the html file below

```
<button onclick='populateList(0, "type=dragon")'>Dragons</button>
```

Comment: you'll need to show how you call `populateList`

Comment: if you call it like `populateList(0, 'type=dragon');` and use `let response = await fetch(APILINKS[url] + query);` and `response = await fetch(APILINKS[url] + query + "&limit=" + count);` it works 100%

Comment: I am calling it from a HTML button <button onclick='populateList(0, "type=dragon")'>Dragons</button>

Comment: As far as I checked your code in my browser, it works. Check your console/network errors in the developer tools of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I checked your code in my browser, it works. Check your console/network errors in the developer tools of your browser. A bit refactored working version (a piece of advice, paginated resources should be fetched in a loop, some APIs cap page size):

```js
async function populateList(resource, query) {
    let queryResults = document.getElementById("queryResults");
    queryResults.innerHTML = "<p>Loading data</p>";

    let results = [];
    
    let next = "https://api.open5e.com/" + resource + "/?" + query;
    while (next !== null) {
      let request = await fetch(next);
      if (request.ok) { // if HTTP-status is 200-299
          let response = await request.json();
          results.push(...response["results"]);
          next = response["next"];
      } else {
          queryResults.innerHTML = "<p>Could not load data</p>";
          return;
      }
    }
    queryResults.innerHTML = "<p>Loaded " + results.length + " items</p>";
}
```

```html
<button onclick='populateList("monsters", "type=dragon")'>Dragons</button>
<div id="queryResults"></div>
```

Comment: I forgot to reply to this, turns out the issue was nothing to do with the code posted here, where I was calling it from was submitting the form and resetting the page